# Hadoop 2.7.3 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Tags: java, hadoop, debian, bigdata

I have problem when i install hadoop on debian jessie, i got warning when run script start-dfs.sh

`hadoop@debian1:~$ /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh
17/03/24 10:40:00 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-debian1.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-debian1.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-debian1.out
17/03/24 10:40:16 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`

i'm running

hadoop-2.7.3, debian jessie (8.7), default java from repo debian

could someone help me to fix the warning ?

Answer (score 1):

Add below lines to `hadoop-env.sh`, it will fix

```
export HADOOP_HOME_WARN_SUPPRESS=1
export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER="WARN,DRFA"
```

Comment: `Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform`.... Huumm I think supress logging this will SOLVE it !!

Comment: Obviously this isn't any kind of a fix, it's just suppressing the warnings

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was adding these lines in .bashrc file:

```
... others enviroment variables... 
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR"
```

After doing this, you need to refresh using this command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Instead of omit the warnings editing hadoop-env.sh, you can use these steps to provide the path of the native library.